# Extract and execute scripts from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery

My AJAX response returns something like this:

```
<div>
..
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
..
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
..
</script>

<div>
..
</div>
```

I want to execute scripts from script tag (should work cross-browserly) and to insert text (divs) to page after.

Comment: Well jQuery has that built in...

Comment: try out [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.
I created such solution:

```
var scripts = [];
$(response).each(function(key, element){
    if ($(element).is('script')) {
        scripts.push(element.innerHTML);
    } else {
        $('test').append($(element));
    }
});
$.each(scripts, function(key, element){
    eval(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `script` tags don't need the `type="text/javascript"` attribute for cross-browser compatibility.

And your JavaScript will execute from the top down. So whatever script comes first will execute first. Add your text insertion last, something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "hello";
```

Comment: On this note, `text/javascript` is the default type for `script` since Netscape ;)

Answer (score 0):

Extract scripts from ajax responses is generally bad practice (caching, security,...).
It's better to handle data (JSON) returned in the ajax response. Consider to use JQuery or another framework since they offer cross-browser functionality and DOM manipulation build-in.

See the following DOM manipulation example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $grouplist = $('#groups');
  $.each(myData, function() {
    $('<li>' + this.name + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
  });
});
```

@ http://jsfiddle.net/qmacro/NJMyD/

If you want to stay with the native functionality without frameworks, javascript offers native dom manipulation functions that may be browser dependant.

When you're adding a new `<javascript>` element to the body, it should be automatically registered.

Comment: New `<javascript>` element?